# Pointer issue not solved

Tags: c, pointers

In the below code, the file test.txt has the following data :

```
192.168.1.1-90    
192.168.2.2-80
```

The output of this is not as expected. I expect the output to be

```
192.168.1.1    
90     
192.168.2.2   
80
```

The current output is

```
192.168.2.2    
80     
192.168.2.2     
80
```

I know that the pointer of str is pointing to the same address in the second iteration as well.

Im just not able to the problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  FILE * fp;
  char * result[10][4];
  int i = 0;
  const char s[2] = "-";
  char temp[50];
  char * value, str[128], * string, t[20], x[29] = "192.168.2.2";
  fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    printf("File doesn't exist\n");
  else {
    while (!feof(fp)) {

      if (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp)) {

        /* get the first value */
        value = strtok(str, s);

        result[i][0] = value;
        printf("IP : %s\n", result[i][0]); //to be removed after testing


        /* get second value */
        value = strtok(NULL, s);

        result[i][1] = value;
        printf("PORT : %s\n", result[i][1]); //to be removed after testing
        i++;
      }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        printf("\n%s\n", result[k][j]);
      }
    }

  }
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Do you need `char *result[10][4];`? Why not just have an array of strings instead, like `char *result[4]`?

Comment: @RoadRunner, its like i want to store the IP and port number separately.

Comment: So, i'm trying to make a row and column scenario, where column one is IP and column 2 is port number

Comment: Related: [Why is `while (!feof(file))` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Oh okay @vatsal511. Yeah then that's fine. I wasn't quite sure what you're aim was.

Comment: So @RoadRunner any help.?

Comment: If you want two columns, then why do declare `result` to have four?

Comment: The code evidently assumes that the input file will never have more than ten lines.  It's ok for it to be unable to handle more, but in that case it should *detect* the case that there are actually more, and fall back to some reasonable, *defined* behavior, such as ignoring the excess or erroring out.  Accustom yourself to writing safe code.

Comment: @Quentin, `while(!feof(file))` is *always* semantically wrong, even if, as in this case, it happens not to break the program.  In cases such as this, it is wrong at least because it is wasteful.  In this particular case, the `while` should be removed, and the `if` statement inside converted into a `while`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I thought about it again, and it *does* in fact introduce a bug: while double-checking for end-of-file is wasteful but harmless, if any other error occurs, the program will loop infinitely. Let me second your previous comment ;)

Comment: @vatsal511 I posted a possible solution below, from what I understand of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { IP = 0, PORT = 1};

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    char result[2][2][16];//2 lines, 2 kinds, 16:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX+NUL
    const char *s = "-";//delimiter
    char *value, line[128];
    int i=0;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File doesn't exist\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(i < 2 && fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
        value = strtok(line, s);
        strcpy(result[i][IP], value);
        printf("IP : %s\n",result[i][IP]);

        value = strtok(NULL, s);
        strcpy(result[i][PORT], value);
        printf("PORT : %s\n",result[i][PORT]);
        i++;
    }
    puts("");
    for (int k=0;k<2;k++){
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
            printf("%s\n",result[k][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when im trying to compare `result[k][j]` (in the final loop) to some string like `192.168.1.1`, i'm unable to do that. Why is that so.?

Comment: @vatsal511 I don't get you. `strcmp(result[k][j], "192.168.1.1") == 0` is true when k : 0, j : 0.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is that you are assigning "value" pointer to elements of "result" array. In your implementation, all the elements of "result" just mirror the value of "value" pointer. Therefore, when you change the value of "value", you also change all the "result" elements.

Because of that, you should use strcpy function after allocating memory for the specific "result" element.

```
value = strtok(str, s);
result[i][0]=malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
strcpy(result[i][0], value);
```

Comment: Not working... Tried what you asked me to. result[i][0]=malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
is being shown illegal

Answer (score -1):

When you want to keep-copy strings you have to use the function `strcpy()`

Instead of `result[i][x] = value` you should do the following

```
strcpy(result[i][x], value);
```

Edit: Before the `strcpy` you have to use `malloc` to allocate memory for the `result[i][x]` string.
eg:

```
result[i][0] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Well, not exactly.  All of the elements of `result` are uninitialized `char` pointers, so your suggested solution produces undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh true true, you have to `malloc` the `result[i][x]`. Adding it in the answer!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) for allocating space for each `ip` and `port`, and freeing them at the end with [`free`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm). Additionally, a struct might be handy here, if you have bigger text files in the future that you want to use.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COLS 2
#define MAXCHAR 10
#define BUFFSIZE 128

void exit_if_null(void *ptr, const char *msg);

int
main(void) {
    FILE *filename;
    char *result[COLS][MAXCHAR+1];
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    char *ip, *port;
    int row, i = 0;

    filename = fopen("ips.txt", "r");

    if (filename == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error reading file!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        while (fgets(buffer, BUFFSIZE, filename) != NULL && i < 2) {
            ip = strtok(buffer, "-");
            port = strtok(NULL, "\n");

            result[i][0] = malloc(strlen(ip)+1);
            exit_if_null(result[i][0], "Initial Allocation");

            result[i][1] = malloc(strlen(port)+1);
            exit_if_null(result[i][1], "Initial Allocation");

            strcpy(result[i][0], ip);
            strcpy(result[i][1], port);

            i++;
        }
    }

    for (row = 0; row < i; row++) {
        printf("%s\n", result[row][0]);
        printf("%s\n", result[row][1]);

        free(result[row][0]);
        free(result[row][1]);

        result[row][0] = NULL;
        result[row][1] = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}

void
exit_if_null(void *ptr, const char *msg) {
    if (!ptr) {
        printf("Unexpected null pointer: %s\n", msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: @vatsal511, what about this solution?

Comment: Im getting the same error which i got in the above code given by @elikatsis void *__cdecl malloc(size_t  _Size)

Comment: you might need to `#include <malloc.h>`